# Laravel whereIn array repetition

Tags: laravel, cookies

```
$item_ids = Cookie::get('name');

if(!is_array($item_ids)){
    $items = Item::find($item_ids)->get();
}
$items = DB::table('items')
            ->whereIn('id', $item_ids )
            ->get();

dd($items);
```

[image]

```
$item_ids in dd($item_ids)
array:5 [▼
  0 => "2"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "2"
  3 => "4"
  4 => "6"
]
```

As you can see in $item_ids 2 was repeated 3 times and I only get one. How to repeat it also 3 times. Is there any Query Builder could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Query builder looks in the database for `id = 2` with the `whereIn` method. There is only one item with id 2 in the database so it only returns one record.

However you can loop through your all your ids again and pull these from your database results. Do this for every id so you get multiple results for same id.

Something like this:

```
$item_ids = Cookie::get('name');

if(!is_array($item_ids)){
    $items = Item::find($item_ids)->get();
}else{
    $items = [];
    $dbItems = Item::whereIn('id',$item_ids)->get();
    foreach($item_ids as $id){
        $items[] = $dbItems->first(function ($key, $value) use ($id) {
            return $value->id == $id;
        });
    }
}

dd($items);
```